# Why and when is the type of a Flow changed during a Deployment?

Tags: deployment, visual-workflow

So, we have this flow which is launched from a quick action which is placed on several layouts. The flow does not contain any screens but is still defined as a screen flow so we can launch it from a quick action.
This has now been deployed between sandboxes using Copado and surprisingly after the deployment the flow has changed to an autolaunched flow in the target sandbox. Upon discovering this we had a good ol session of swearing :-)

How is this possible?

Here is an excerpt from the Flows metadata as it is in our DEV sandbox and in the Git branch corresponding to the target sandbox:
[image]

Here is the same excerpt after retrieving the Flows metadata from the target sandbox today:
[image]

And here is the list metadata result from Workbench:
[image]
(I'm 100% sure that nobody went into the sandbox and changed the flows type 5 seconds after the deployment)

This is a mystery to me :-)

Anybody any ideas what has happened?
Thank you!

Comment: Are both sandboxes on the same release? Winter 20 vs. Spring 20? Also, are you deploying the flows as active or is a prior version still active in the target?

Comment: you also need to rule out Copado here. Try the deploy using Workbench, ant, or Changesets as an experiment. Also, if there is source control in between each sandbox deploy, check your repo

Comment: Both sandboxes are on Spring '20 and also were since before the deployment.
This was the first time the Flow was deployed and it was deployed as active.

Comment: Due to its dependencies it is slightly difficult to create a fresh sandbox where we could try out a fresh deployment of the flow with different deployment mechanisms. We however experimented and deployed another flow which is a Screen Flow but does not contain any elements forcing it to be interactive using a Change Set and we did not see that the Flow is converted to an Autolaunched Flow in the target org.